# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'state'

Tags: python, csv

Hey I'm new to coding in python. Trying to parse through a csv and separate good phone numbers from bad phone numbers. Here is what I have so far. I get an error: ****AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'state'****
Any ideas how to fix this..I know I do not have a class defined but I don't know how else I can separate the data.

```
# Description: cleans phone number field and returns fields that need manual edits
# Date Modified: 10/22/13

#Working on making two separate files...good and bad phone.

import csv
import string
import time
import re
import pprint
import codecs
start_time = time.time()

# remove all non-numeric characters from phone numbers
all=string.maketrans('','')
nodigs=all.translate(all, string.digits + string.ascii_letters + " ")
nospace=all.translate(all, string.digits + string.ascii_letters)    

def main():
    # creates new file to dump clean data
    fout = codecs.open('clean_phone.csv', 'w', 'latin-1')
    writer = csv.writer(fout)


    #Create dictionary for easy reading/location
    office_list= ['Office Phone']
    alt_list= ['Alternative Phone']
    fax_list= ['Fax']

    # Creates boolean to allow for delegation into good/bad csv files 
    state = True

    # Begin parsing Office Phone
    with codecs.open('companies.csv', 'r', 'latin-1') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = reader.next()
        id_index=headers.index("ID")
        office_phone_index=headers.index("Office Phone")
        alt_phone_index=office_phone_index + 1
        fax_index=office_phone_index + 2
        condensed_header = [headers[id_index], headers[office_phone_index], headers[alt_phone_index], headers[fax_index]]
        writer.writerow(condensed_header)

        i=2
        for row in reader:

            # Clean Office Phone
            phoneNumber= row[office_phone_index]
            goodNumber=phoneNumber.translate(all, nodigs)
            if len(goodNumber)>12:
                numberParts= goodNumber.rpartition("%x")
                if numberParts[0]:
                    goodNumber=numberParts[0]
                else:
                    state = False
                    office_list.append("row %d: %s" %(i, goodNumber))            
            row[office_phone_index]=goodNumber.translate(all, nospace)

            # Clean Alternate Phone
            phoneNumber2= row[alt_phone_index]
            goodNumber2=phoneNumber2.translate(all, nodigs)
            if len(goodNumber2)>12:
                numberParts2= goodNumber2.rpartition("%x")
                if numberParts2[0]:
                    goodNumber2=numberParts2[0]
                else:
                    state = False
                    alt_list.append("row %d: %s" %(i, goodNumber2))
            row[alt_phone_index]=goodNumber2.translate(all, nospace)

            # Clean FAX
            phoneNumber3= row[fax_index]
            goodNumber3=phoneNumber3.translate(all, nodigs)
            if len(goodNumber3)>12:
                numberParts3= goodNumber3.rpartition("%x")
                if numberParts3[0]:
                    goodNumber3=numberParts[0]
                else:
                    state = False
                    fax_list.append("row %d: %s" %(i, goodNumber3))
            row[fax_index]=goodNumber3.translate(all, nospace)

            # Write Row (write to a good or bad list)
            condensed_row = [row[id_index],row[office_phone_index], row[alt_phone_index], row[fax_index]]

            #Bad Phone List
            if office_list.state == False:
                fout = codecs.open('manual_office_phone_fix.csv', 'w', 'latin-1')
                writer.writerow(condensed_row)
            if alt_phone_list.state == False:
                fout = codecs.open('manual_alt_phone_fix.csv', 'w', 'latin-1')
                writer.writerow(condensed_row)
            if fax_list.state == False:
                fout = codecs.open('manual_fax_phone_fix.csv', 'w', 'latin-1')
                writer.writerow(condensed_row)  
            #Good Phone List for Manual Edit
            else:
                writer.writerow(condensed_row)
            #Move to next item
            i+=1    

        #Print Results to the Console
        print "The following phone numbers need manual review." + "\n"
        pprint.pprint(office_list)
        pprint.pprint(alt_list)
        pprint.pprint(fax_list)
    fout.close()
main()
```

Comment: Post the full traceback for the error.

Comment: Also post less of the code.  See http://sscce.org/ for an explanation of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
if office_list.state == False:
```

its looking for `state` to be an attribute of `office_list`, which it is not. I see above where you've set `state` equal to `false` in a few place. I would recommend making 3 different variables and using those for you if statement. A `office_list_state`, `alt_phone_list_state`, and a `fax_list_state` and use those as your booleans. You will need to make sure they have a value when you reach your if blocks, so you might want to give them an initial value of `True`. I haven't examined the code to carefully to know what you need there.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Looks like you need to keep track of a state for several different fields. Have you tried a dictionary? Something like this at the top of your loop:

```
states = {'office_phone': True,
          'alt_phone': True,
          'fax': True}
```

Then, rather than doing `state = False`, do `states['office_phone'] = False`, for example. When you want to check the state, do `if states['office_phone']:`.

Hope that helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what's happening here:

```
if office_list.state == False
```

You're calling `.state` on a `list` instance defined as

```
office_list= ['Office Phone']
```

which doesn't have a `state` method. Furthermore, `office_list` seems to contain strings, which don't have a `.state` method either.

It seems like you've either made a basic mistake and haven't realized/found it, or that you're expecting something "magic" to happen automatically without understanding what the syntax `.state` means in the first place. The only thing called `state` is your variable `state` which does indeed hold boolean values, but it is in now way accessible as a method of lists—I'm not sure what made you think it would be.

If you need to keep 3 different states, one for each of the lists, just use 3 different state variables called `state_office`, `alt_state` and `fax_state` and access those instead. And never try to do magic things without understanding what's going on and expect Python to just do what you mean.